# Is it possible to switch between multiple legends when switching between base groups?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am visualizing some vector data using leaflet in r which has multiple non-spatial variables that a user might be interested in. I want to allow the user to select one variable that will determine the color of the features. I accomplish this with the `baseGroups` argument to the `addLayersControl` function, where each group is the same data with a different color palette. This works fine for switching the colors of the features themselves, but does not allow me to switch between legends- every legend I add is always shown, even if I use the appropriate `group` within `addLegend`. See the example code and screenshot below:

```
data <- data.frame(long = c(-93.2, -93, -93.5), lat = c(44.9, 45, 44.9), 
               var1 = c(1,2,3), var2 = c(10, 9, 1))

pal1 <- colorNumeric(palette = "Blues", domain = data$var1)
pal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = "Reds", domain = data$var2)

leaflet(data) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(color = ~pal1(var1), group = "var1") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(color = ~pal2(var2), group = "var2") %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal1, values = ~var1, group = "var1") %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal2, values = ~var2, group = "var2") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("var1", "var2"), position = "topleft")
```

[image]

If I replace `baseGroups` with `overlayGroups` in my layers control, this works as expected, and only the legends for the selected groups are shown. However, this option isn't ideal because I don't want the user to be able to select multiple groups or deselect all groups.

[image]

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50641092/r-leaflet-map-change-legends-based-on-selected-layer-group) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770641/how-to-hide-toggle-legends-based-on-addlayercontrol-in-leaflet-for-r) are quite similar to mine, but the accepted solutions both use `overlayGroups`, while I want to stick with `baseGroups`. I'm also hoping to avoid using shiny, if possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems legends in `baseGroups` won't remove/re-added as if in `overlayGroups`, which can be further proved by the persistence of legends even after calling `hideGroup("var1")`.

A crude workaround can be adding an event handler to hide/unhide legends according to the current selected group of `baseGroups` using `group = "<groupName>"` as a key, and nothing else should need to be changed. For example:

```r
htmlwidgets::onRender("
    function(el, x) {
      var updateLegend = function () {
          var selectedGroup = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')[0].nextSibling.innerText.substr(1);

          document.querySelectorAll('.legend').forEach(a => a.hidden=true);
          document.querySelectorAll('.legend').forEach(l => {
            if (l.children[0].children[0].innerText == selectedGroup) l.hidden=false;
          });
      };
      updateLegend();
      this.on('baselayerchange', e => updateLegend());
    }")
```

### Demo

[image: demo of workaround]

#### Source of Demo

```r
require(leaflet)


data <- data.frame(long = c(-93.2, -93, -93.5), lat = c(44.9, 45, 44.9), 
                   var1 = c(1,2,3), var2 = c(10, 9, 1))

pal1 <- colorNumeric(palette = "Blues", domain = data$var1)
pal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = "Reds", domain = data$var2)

leaflet(data) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(color = ~pal1(var1), group = "var1") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(color = ~pal2(var2), group = "var2") %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal1, values = ~var1, group = "var1") %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal2, values = ~var2, group = "var2") %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("var1", "var2"), 
                   position = "topleft",
                   options = layersControlOptions(collapsed=F)) %>%
  htmlwidgets::onRender("
    function(el, x) {
      var updateLegend = function () {
          var selectedGroup = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')[0].nextSibling.innerText.substr(1);

          document.querySelectorAll('.legend').forEach(a => a.hidden=true);
          document.querySelectorAll('.legend').forEach(l => {
            if (l.children[0].children[0].innerText == selectedGroup) l.hidden=false;
          });
      };
      updateLegend();
      this.on('baselayerchange', e => updateLegend());
    }")
```

Comment: This answer is great but it does not appear to work if the leaflet object is output to an r markdown document that uses tabs.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use 'overlayGroups' instead of 'baseGroups'? Because then you wouldn't need necessarily the 'htmlwidgets::onRender'

Comment: @g07kore Yes, it is easier and PO is aware of this approach, but as PO stated "this option isn't ideal because I don't want the user to be able to select multiple groups or deselect all groups".

Comment: This is very helpful but fragile. The JS code requires the legend title to be exactly the same as the name in the layers control. This can easily break, for example if you give a title to the legend.

Comment: @Quar thank you! I had exactly this problem and this was just the solution I was looking for.